# Writing bash scripts for changing Mac OS / OSX settings?

Tags: bash, macos

I am not sure if I am asking this question properly, but I am trying write a script to change some settings on Mac OS Sierra, similar to this script which sets the clock in the menubar to appear as analog:

```
killall Dock;
defauls write com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog -bool true;
killall SystemUIServer;
```

Instead, I would like to select a different keyboard layout which I have created using Karabiner elements, which also appears in the menubar, and I can change it using the mouse.

My question is basically, how can I figure out what commands to put in my script to make changes like this? Is there a way to record commands that are run when making mouse actions, and then simply paste those commands into a script and alias it to some shortcut? Any help on how to become proficient writing scripts like this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For scripting that interacts directly with macOS, you're much better off writing **AppleScript** over shell. AppleScript is Apple's proprietary scripting language that contains many ways to interact with the operating system. In addition, AppleScript was designed to be a very human readable language.

Plenty of documentation and tutorials for AppleScript can be found through a quick google search. Here are some Apple webpages to get you started:

[Introduction to AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html)
[AppleScript fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html)

To write AppleScripts, open up Script Editor, located in Applications > Utilities.

An example script to toggle macOS Sierra's dark mode, would be:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell appearance preferences
    if dark mode is false then
        set dark mode to true
    else
        set dark mode to false
    end if
end tell
end tell
```